# Templated Class with argument - Error during use

Tags: class, templates, constructor, arguments

I have a templates class for the type of machine in a hospital room:

```
template <class T_machine>
class hospital_room
{
  public:
    hospital_room(const int room_num); 
......
```

With this constructor in the hospital_room.hpp file:

```
template <class T_machine>
hospital_room<T_machine>::hospital_room(const int room_num)
{
  m_room_num = room_num;
}
```

However, when I try to declare a hospital room, like this

```
hospital_room<x_rayer>(1) test;
```

It gives me an error, saying it expected a semicolon after the (1). What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There could potentially be several problems here, but for starters, if you're trying to instantiate a `hospital_room` object with a `room_num` of 1, you should do:

`hospital_room<x_rayer> test(1);`